# Find files with certain filesize in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, filesize

i need to find all index.php files with file size of 1.905 bytes.
I have over 700+ websites and 2/5 of them are hacked and have index.php with this filesize. 
Please help me!!!

Comment: Did you do any research on that? What is your question actually? "man find" command would be a good place to start..

Answer (score 3):

To find files under `/var/www` with name index.php and size of exactly 1905 bytes:

```
find /var/www -name index.php -size 1905c
```